# Fix Angle into Direction

Tags: c#, xna, angle

I want to fix an angle.

Problem - video: https://youtu.be/5LGbYguG4P0

For example(s):

I have angle 90, that I want to fix for 45 degrees (so it can't go less/more than (90 - 45) or (90 + 45).

I have attempted multiple methods over the last couple of hours, aswelll as searched the heck out of the internet.

Some have worked, mostly, in that they "wrap" wrongly due to built-in angle wrapping (I think it's wrap is -Pi to Pi), so when it reaches -Pi or Pi, and exceeds, it wraps, and does a big jump to the opposite angle.

Attempt(s):

```
    public static float AngleBound(float Angle, float BoundAngle, ushort Degrees)
    {
        float A = MathHelper.ToDegrees(Angle), BA = MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle), DMin = (BA - Degrees), DMax = (BA + Degrees);
        return MathHelper.ToRadians(MathHelper.Max(DMin, MathHelper.Min(DMax, A)));
    }

    public static float AngleBound(float Angle, float BoundAngle, ushort Degrees)
    {
        return MathHelper.ToRadians((float)Wrap((MathHelper.ToDegrees(Angle) + 180), ((MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle) + 180) + (Degrees / 2f)), ((MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle) + 180) - (Degrees / 2f))));
    }

    public static float AngleBound(float Angle, float BoundAngle, ushort Degrees)
    {
        return MathHelper.ToRadians((float)Wrap(MathHelper.ToDegrees(Angle), (MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle) + (Degrees * 1)), (MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle) - (Degrees * 1))));
    }
```

Explanation:

```
Angle = 60 (Passed in as Radians)
AngleBound = 90 (Passed in as Radians)
Degrees = 45 (Passed in as Degrees)
Wanted Result: Angle bound by (90 - 45) - (90 + 45)
Wanted Result: Angle bound by (AngleBound - Degrees) - (AngleBound + Degrees)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers so far do not take into account that if you do `Clamp(380, 300, 380 % 20)`. Angle becomes 20 (which is good) but in the next iteration `Clamp(20, 300, 380)` angle becomes 300 (which is causing the weird jump).

Lets revisit the problem:

Lets first define some terminology to make sure we're all on the same page. (Your wording got me a bit confused, but it shouldn't be important).

`TargetAngle`, the angle which you do not want to deviate from by more than a small amount

`Deviation`, the min and max angle (`TargetAngle - Deviation`, `TargetAngle + Deviation`)

`InputAngle`, the angle the algorithm should fix

Then there are three cases

1. `TargetAngle - Deviation >= 0 && TargetAngle + Deviation < 360`

The simplest problem. The solution is to use clamp. `angle = MathHelper.Clamp(InputAngle, TargetAngle - Deviation, TargetAngle + Deviation);`

2. `TargetAngle - Deviation > 0 && TargetAngle + Deviation > 360`

Lets see what happens if we take `TargetAngle = 350` and `deviation = 20` the acceptable ranges are now 350-360 and 0-10. In code this is:

```
// Fix the lower bound, angle might be larger than 360    
if(angle >= TargetAngle - Deviation)
{
    MathHelper.Clamp(angle, TargetAngle - Deviation, TargetAngle + Deviation);
}

// Wrap around, let angle be in the 0-360 range
angle = angle % 360

// If angle has become, or is smaller than the minimum value, check if
// its in the lower range (0-10) in our example
if(angle < TargetAngle - Deviation)
{
    MathHelper.Clamp(angle, 0, (TargetAngle + Deviation) % 360);
}
```

3. `TargetAngle - Deviation < 0 && TargetAngle + Deviation < 360`

Lets take `TargetAngle = 10` and `deviation = 20`. The acceptable ranges are now 0-30 350-360. You can solve this in the same way I solved the 2nd case.

Note that the code can obviously be simplified. But first cover all cases, then test if it works, then start simplifying :).

Comment: It's rotated by 90 degrees, and still has a bad wrap at 180~ degrees.

Comment: It is rotated by 90 degrees? How do you mean that? The code doesn't do anything to the angle if its not outside the range so how can it rotate it for you? Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere? Can you show your implementation of my example and how you use it?

Comment: Angle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(Angle); BoundAngle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(BoundAngle);
            if (Angle >= (BoundAngle - Degrees)) Angle = MathHelper.Clamp(Angle, (BoundAngle - Degrees), (BoundAngle + Degrees));
            Angle = Angle % 360;
            if (Angle < (BoundAngle - Degrees)) Angle = MathHelper.Clamp(Angle, 0, (BoundAngle + Degrees) % 360);
            return MathHelper.ToRadians(Angle);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static float AngleBound (float Angle, float BoundAngle, ushort Degrees)
{
    var RadDegrees = Degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    var MinBound = BoundAngle - RadDegrees; 
    var MaxBound = BoundAngle + RadDegrees; 

    if (MinBound < 0)
        MinBound += 2*Math.PI;

    if (MaxBound > 2*Math.PI)
        MinBound -= 2*Math.PI;

    if (Angle <= MinBound)
        return MinBound;

    if (Angle >= MaxBound)
        return MaxBound;

    return Angle;
}
```

Comment: It still happens, whenever the Angle wraps, it's like it doesn't let me pass 180 degrees otherwise it stops. :(

Comment: Can you post an image or drawing of what's happening?

Comment: It'd be hard to illustrate that, a video would do it - but if you want to TeamView that'd be amazing, if not I really am willing to do a video.

Comment: You can contact me if you think it's better, my email and steam is on my profile but a video would be interesting because I might not be able to help, this way other users will understand what's happening better.

Comment: Video added, and added on Steam @ DcrewGames